# Wordpress One Page website loop and PolyLang widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing my portfolio website and I decided to use Wordpress and PolyLang widget to show my site in multi languages. My website is One Page so instead of changing sites with a loop i'm using this loop to show website content as a post:

```
<?php
$post_id = 21;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $queried_post->post_title;
echo $queried_post->post_content;
?>
```

The problem with this solution is- when I translate a single post, the ID of a translated post changes, and my website obviously shows the same post language as before.

Can You please help me how to use Wordpress with One Page Websites and how to use it with PolyLang widget?

Please consider me as a PHP Newbie.

Comment: instead of static id use $post_id = get_the_ID();

Comment: Ok that obviously works, but how? :D I'm gonna have multiple ID's on the whole website so when the wordpress knows whitch one to put it?

Comment: @AkshayShah As I suspected - this work only for one post, as I say - I have a lot of this loops on my One Page Website, every last one is technically on index.php

Comment: now i understood your problem while doing the loop you are not getting the right post id of selected language.  am i right now?

Comment: @AkshayShah when I use $post_id = get_the_ID(); Im getting all my posts everywhere, I mean on every single subpage.